# can't install deis with 1 coreos node

Tags: deis

I've tried to follow the setup, I successfully started a bare-metal (though really a VM) by installing coreos and then installing deis, however I think I have a problem of having only 1 coreos instance.

The procedure stalls at:

```
deisctl install platform
● ▴ ■
■ ● ▴ Installing Deis...
▴ ■ ●

Storage subsystem...
deis-store-daemon.service: loaded
deis-store-monitor.service: loaded
deis-store-metadata.service: loaded
deis-store-volume.service: loaded
deis-store-gateway.service: loaded
Logging subsystem...
deis-logger.service: loaded
deis-logspout.service: loaded
Control plane...
deis-cache.service: loaded
deis-database.service: loaded
deis-registry.service: loaded
deis-controller.service: loaded
deis-builder.service: loaded
Data plane...
deis-publisher.service: loaded
Routing mesh...
deis-router@1.service: loaded
.... .. ..
```

I can find old documentation about 1 node setups, but they seem out of date, is the 1 node (dev) setup still supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of late, Deis requires a minimum of 3 nodes for both dev and production setups. This is due to ceph requiring a minimum of 3 nodes to achieve quorum.

Comment: Also, etcd clusters have no failure tolerance with one node, so 3 is required: https://coreos.com/docs/cluster-management/scaling/etcd-optimal-cluster-size/